# How can delete or edit an entity orion context broker

Tags: fiware-orion

We have an entity alredy created in Orion Context Broker, and we need to add one attribute tag. The structure is something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<updateContextRequest>
  <contextElementList>
    <contextElement>
      <entityId type="entity_id" isPattern="false">
        <id>entity_id</id>
      </entityId>
      <contextAttributeList>
        <contextAttribute>
          <name>param1_name</name>
          <type>param1_type</type>
          <contextValue>param1_</contextValue>
        </contextAttribute>
        <contextAttribute>
          <name>param2_name</name>
          <type>param2_type</type>
          <contextValue>param2_value</contextValue>
        </contextAttribute>
      </contextAttributeList>
    </contextElement>
  </contextElementList>
  <updateAction>APPEND</updateAction>
</updateContextRequest>
```

We need to remove the entity and recreate it with new attributes, or you can add an attribute without having to remove it?

How is the procedure to delete and edit it? (edit if it's possible)

Regards,
Ismael

Comment: I need to edit entityId Type tag, from 
<entityId type="" isPattern="false"> 
to 
<entityId type="entity_id" isPattern="false">. 

How could edit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the attributes associated to an entity, you don't need to delete and re-create the entity. The section on [Adding and removing attributes with APPEND and DELETE in updateContext](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Adding_and_removing_attributes_with_APPEND_and_DELETE_in_updateContext) in the Orion user manual explains how to dynamically remove and add attributes to existing entities.

Regarding the entity ID and type, they are inmutable fields. They are "intristic" parts of the entity definition, thus changing them equal to destroying the entity and create it again. Entity deletion is described in the user manual at section on [Deleting entities](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Deleting_entities).

Finally, current version (Orion 0.18.1) doesn't allow to change the service and/or serivePath to which one entity belong, but probably the API will be evolved in the future to allow that.

Comment: Following this manual, we try this:

# mongo localhost/entities
> db.entities.remove({"_id.id": "finesce_meteo", "_id.type": ""})

But when we try to list all entities created, the "finesce_meteo" entity is still here:

curl localhost:1026/ngsi10/contextEntities/finesce_meteo -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/xml' | xmllint --format -

Comment: Deleting at DB is one of the mechanisms. You can also do it through API if using Orion 0.11.0 or newer, as described in the aforementioned manual section.